# Hangfire pause/resume job using dashboard

Tags: c#, .net, hangfire

I need to pause/resume or remove(already exist)/add(not exist) jobs on hangfire dashboard when i need. Is there a way this option add to dashboard. I couldn't find any documentation about modify of dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pause/resume in hangfire. When a job is started the method is called and runs till it finishs. All you could do is add a `CancellationToken` as argument to your method and check in your code if the token is cancelled. When you press on the dashboard the delete or requeue button, the cancellation token will be set and you can exit your job method.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have a job that runs at specific times every day. When I notice an error, I don't want this job to run during its other scheduled times. For example, it runs at 2pm, 4pm, and 6pm every day, but I noticed an error at 2pm. I want to stop it from running at 4pm, 6pm, and the following days until the error is fixed. The Delete button solves my problem to some extent, but I still need to restart the application for the job to run again. I don't want to do this.

Comment: I guess the re-run is done by using recurring jobs? If yes, hangfire will create a new job for each configured point in time. So deleting will only harm this single point in time not the other jobs. AFAIK hangfire doesn't support your case. Instead your job has to check at the beginning if some error flag has been set and if yes, immediately exit the method. Depending on your needs you could simply exit to set the state to succeeded (but did nothing) or throw an exception to get the job into failed state.

Comment: The error flag has to be managed outside of hangfire (e.g. SQL server, redis cache, file system, registry, etc) depending on what is available in your system context and is accessible from all hangfire clients watching your worker queue.

Comment: this method makes more sense if there is no solution by hangfire